# file_put_contents() failed to open stream

Tags: php, html, pdf, path, dompdf

I want to save a file directly with dompdf.
If my file name is a variable, it comes with the errormessage that in the title.
My code: 
`$output = $dompdf->output();
 file_put_contents("../pdf/".$filename.".pdf", $output);`

If I write a simple word instead of the path, it works beautifully.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Because it depends on what the current working drive and directory is. You are using relative directory access because you start it off with "..". The current working directory you are trying to write to may not contain the pdf directory. 
Use chdir before file_put_contents to set the folder location, then write to it.

Like:

```
chdir($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "/pdf/");
file_put_contents($filename . ".pdf", $output);
```

Make sure also that your user has write permissions to the PDF folder.